# How to print lines with blank 5th field in CSV

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk

I have to check if the fifth field is empty in a CSV file. This is my file:

```
1,abc,543,87,DATA,fsg; 
1,abc,543,87,,fsg; 
1,abc,543,87,DATA,fsg; 
1,abc,543,88,,fsg; 
1,abc,543,,DATA,fsg;
```

As you can see, the second and fourth lines have an empty fifth field. I want to print all these lines.

Result should be this:

```
1,abc,543,87,,fsg;
1,abc,543,87,,fsg;
```

Comment: No, fifth value is empty in only 2 lines.

Answer (score 13):

Another `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, '!length($5)' file
1,abc,543,87,,fsg; 
1,abc,543,88,,fsg;
```

Comment: suggestion: simply using `awk -F, '!$5' file` because the fifth field is empty and not including spaces.

Comment: @KasiyA: It will fail with $5 = 0.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a different field separator (by default space) with the `-F` option, and then you only have to check if the 5th column is empty:

```
awk -F',' '{if($5==""){print $0}' myfile
```

or more concisely:

```
awk -F, '$5==""' myfile
```

--

And with the sed command:

```
sed -n '/,,[^,]*$/p' myfile
```

Don't print (`-n`) except if it's matching `/,,[^,]*$/` that is it ends (`...$`) with `,,` (5th field empty) + a 6th field that does not contain a `,` (`[^,]` = everything except a comma).
Note that if you have more than 6 fields, the command won't work as expected.

Comment: the `sed` solution *does* work for lines with more than six fields - and for those with fewer. it just prints lines in which there is no more than one field between the empty one and end of line. And so it prints `,,` probably.

Answer (score 4):

A simple `awk` would suffice:

```
awk -F, '$5==""' your_file
```

**Explanation**

- The field separator is set to `,` (`-F ,`)
- The default action of `awk` is to print the current record. We ensure this only happens when the fifth field is blank (`$5 == ""`)

Answer (score 2):

With `grep` (as asked):

```
grep -e '.*,.*,.*,.*,,' input
```

although this will match lines that have empty fields after the 5th

Comment: this will match any number of fields before the fifth as well. you want a `^` head-of-line anchor and to use `[^,]*` rather than `.*` i believe.

Comment: @mikeserv In that case it should match the last line of the example input, shouldn't it. Or do you mean something else? There is certainly room for improvement.

Comment: i said that backwards, kind of - i mean that 5 fields is a minimum here - youll get any amount of any character - to include commas or the null string- separated by commas 5 times at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `awk` command:

```
$ awk '/^(.*,){4},.*/' filename
1,abc,543,87,,fsg;
1,abc,543,88,,fsg;
```

The regexp test for any character followed by a `,` four times, and after that the next character must be another `,` (fifth blank field) followed by whatever.

Comment: do you you want `[^,]*,` there? i dont know `awk` well - but i know elsewhere that statement could get a lot more than 4 comma delimited fields.

Answer (score 1):

A Pythonic solution:

```
python3 -c 'import sys, csv;  csv.writer(sys.stdout).writerows(filter(lambda record: record[4] == "", csv.reader(sys.stdin)))' < input.csv
```

- Using the `csv` module, we parse `stdin`, and filter any lines which have an empty fifth element (index 4, since we index from 0).
- The filtered set then written out using the `csv` module to `stdout`.

Comment: that's going to first slurp the whole file into a list though

Comment: @1_CR Updated to use `filter`.

Comment: i prefer generator solutions , so i would recast that to `writerows(record for record in csv.reader(sys.stdin) if record[4] == ""))`, +1 anyways

Answer (score 0):

with `sed` maybe:

```
sed -n 's/,/,\n/4;s/\n,/,/p'
```

Or even:

```
sed -n '/^\([^,]*,\)\{4\},/p'
```

The above should work for any `grep` as well - just leave off the bits before and after `/` chars. In some `sed`s you may want a literal newline instead of `n` in the first `s///`ubstitution.

Answer (score 0):

you can also find the null value for 5th column in list of fileS (BULK OF FILE)  and print the record with its file name.

```
awk -F',' '$5 == "" {printf FILENAME"="$0"\n"}' *common_filepattern*
```

explanation:

- `-F,` set field limit to ,
- `$5 ==""` is  column 5 to null
- `FILENAME` = file name is the keyword to print the name of the file